# How do I show related posts from categories instead of tags?

Tags: wp-query, categories, tags

I am trying to change this wordpress function given in my theme to show posts from category instead of tags.

But due to wordpress beginner i am unable to do this.

Please help me to change this code.

```
<div id="tabs_content_container2">
                            <div id="tab3" class="tab_content2" style="display: block;">
                                <ul class="mv_list_small">
                                <?php  
                                    $orig_post = $post;  
                                    global $post;  
                                    $tags = wp_get_post_($post->ID);  
                                    if ($tags) {  
                                    $tag_ids = array();  
                                    foreach($tags as $individual_tag) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;  
                                    $args=array(  
                                    'tag__in' => $tag_ids,  
                                    'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),  
                                    'posts_per_page'=>10, // Number of related posts to display.  
                                    'ignore_sticky_posts'=>1  
                                    );  
                                    $my_query = new wp_query( $args ); 
                                    $num=1; 
                                    while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {  
                                    $my_query->the_post();
                                ?>
                                    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
```

and after searching on internet i also got the code for related post to show from category. But unable to replace it correctly. Here is the code from internet.

[How to show related posts by category](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41272/how-to-show-related-posts-by-category)

help me to change my default tag code with the category code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the function `wp_get_post_terms()` you can select the taxonomy. the default is `post_tag` you can change it to `category`.

And in the `WP_Query` args you need to change the `tag__in` to `category__in`.

```
// get the categories
$categories = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'category');
if ($categories) {
    $categories_ids = array();
    foreach($categories as $individual_cat) $categories_ids[] = $individual_cat->term_id;
    $args=array(
        'category__in' => $categories_ids, // Select posts from this categories
        'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
        'posts_per_page'=>10, // Number of related posts to display.
        'ignore_sticky_posts'=>1
    );

    $my_query = new wp_query( $args );
    $num=1;
    while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        $my_query->the_post();

        ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                ...
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello thanks for shibi's answer.

But while searching the same thing on internet i got exactly what i needed.

If someone want to have a look check here.

Initially my code was this and using tags to display related posts.

```
<?php $orig_post = $post; global $post; $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID); if ($tags) { $tag_ids = array(); foreach($tags as $individual_tag) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id; $args=array( 'tag__in' => $tag_ids, 'post__not_in' => array($post->ID), 'posts_per_page'=>5, // Number of related posts that will be shown. 'caller_get_posts'=>1 ); $my_query = new wp_query( $args ); if( $my_query->have_posts() ) { echo '<div id="relatedposts"><h3>Related Posts</h3><ul>'; while( $my_query->have_posts() ) { $my_query->the_post(); ?> <li><div class="relatedthumb"><a href="<? the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a></div> <div class="relatedcontent"> <h3><a href="<? the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3> <?php the_time('M j, Y') ?> </div> </li> <? } echo '</ul></div>'; } } $post = $orig_post; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

and i wanted to change this to related post by categories. As i am a beginner i didn't know to play with wordpress php thing.

But fortunately i got what i needed.

```
<?php $orig_post = $post; global $post; $categories = get_the_category($post->ID); if ($categories) { $category_ids = array(); foreach($categories as $individual_category) $category_ids[] = $individual_category->term_id; $args=array( 'category__in' => $category_ids, 'post__not_in' => array($post->ID), 'posts_per_page'=> 2, // Number of related posts that will be shown. 'caller_get_posts'=>1 ); $my_query = new wp_query( $args ); if( $my_query->have_posts() ) { echo '<div id="related_posts"><h3>Related Posts</h3><ul>'; while( $my_query->have_posts() ) { $my_query->the_post();?> <li><div class="relatedthumb"><a href="<? the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a></div> <div class="relatedcontent"> <h3><a href="<? the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3> <?php the_time('M j, Y') ?> </div> </li> <? } echo '</ul></div>'; } } $post = $orig_post; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

you need to scroll to check the complete code else you can check the below page.

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-related-posts-with-a-thumbnail-without-using-plugins/

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
wp_get_post_tags()
```

TO

```
get_the_category()
```

That's all

`get_the_category()` will help you to get category by ID. There is no need to change anything else in your code even if variable name is `$tags`. They are just variables, nothing else in your case

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?