# What is $post->ID

Tags: posts, id

I was going through the following code

'post__not_in' => array($post->ID) but I am unable to understand this.

What information does this supply $post->ID

Answer (score 2):

The post ID.

It's not possible to say any more without more context. If I had to guess `$post` in this case is a [`WP_Post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_post/) object that represents the current post and the author of the post wants to get some posts while excluding the current post. Just be aware that doing so this way is typically [a bad idea](https://docs.wpvip.com/technical-references/code-quality-and-best-practices/using-post__not_in/).

Comment: I agree with @jacob-peattie, but to clarify, it's not just trying to eliminate the current post that's bad.  It's using post__not_in that affects performance... as Mr Peattie's link further explains.

Comment: I am tryin to show related posts on single post page and going through this post https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30039/how-to-display-related-posts-from-same-category